# Execute a function after $.ajax success without putting it in a callback directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function where many parts of my code call it.

```
function test() {
  $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'GET',
    success : {
      verifyID();
      verifyName();
      verifyBlah();
    }
  });
}
```

and I have this other function:

```
addProductCart(productID);
```

Before I call `addProductCart()`, I need to call test function, but, other processes call test function.

I'd like to do this:

```
test() ---> if test ok (success) ----> addProductCart()
```

But I can't set my function (addProductCart) into success test function because, like I said, many other processes call test function.

How can I do this?

Comment: probably need to see the other code as well, to see what the test function is doing, and what the ones calling them is using test for

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call#answer-14220323

Comment: What about making the test function return a boolean and just put an if statement in the success block? Not sure if I understand correctly the question.

Comment: The promises solution shown below is probably best, but you could also modify `test()` to accept optional arguments that specify additional callbacks to be run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Use Promises!

Return a promise from the `test` function like so:

```
function test() {
  return $.ajax({ // <----- Notice the return statement here
    url : url,
    type : 'GET',
    success : {
      verifyID();
      verifyName();
      verifyBlah();
    }
  });
}
```

When you need to use this function to test something and execute another piece of code when this passes you can do :

```
test().then(function(data, textStatus){
  //do thing 1
  addProductCart()
  // you can use data or textStatus returned by your ajax function here too!
});

test(someParam).then(function(data, textStatus){ // <--- You can even pass parameters to test function like here, and make it do different ajax call based on your param
  //do thing 2
});
```

For more details on how this works see the [jQuery docs for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR).  function

Here's a great [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises) on concept of JavaScript Promises to get you started if you are unfamiliar with them.

Comment: Where is the promise returned from the test function?

Comment: $.ajax returns the promise. If you read my answer, I have the same test function as OP but have a return statement before that.

Comment: Ah right that's nice, so your function remains the same, you return the ajax object and then use it differently depending on what you need done no the callback

Comment: I was thrown off by test(someParam) in the next line, that's irrelevant right? The function doesn't accept any arguments as is?

Comment: not as is, but its goes to show that you could if you wanted to pass a parameter, and change same test() function's behavior based on a param. Comes in handy to keep the code DRY and reuse the function.

Comment: maybe `async:false` would help?